# 400 Bad Request by ActiveCollab REST-API

Tags: rest, http-status-code-400, activecollab

I'm trying to do a GET-request to ActiveCollab REST-API using Postman. I want to get the time-records filtered by date for a project. I added my Access-Token to the header and my time period JSON format, of which I want to get the results to body in.
As result, I get "400 Bad Request".

URL:

```
https://*/projects/29/time-records/filtered-by-date
```

Body (JSON):

```
{
    "from": "2021-08-01",
    "to": "2021-08-31"
}
```

I'm able to do other requests with my access-token and I added my parameters in the pattern of the examples in the documentation *(https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/time-records/filtered-by-date.html)*.

The problem did not seem to be with Postman, as I tried to use other applications as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments that you prepared should be sent through query string, not as a request body:

```
https://*/projects/29/time-records/filtered-by-date?from=YYYY-MM-DD&to=YYYY-MM-DD
```

When these arguments are omitted, system returns 400 Bad Request response.